# Object State inside of R package

Tags: r, r-package

I'm building an R package that gets data like so.

```
getdata <- function(uri ="dummyuri.csv"){
  httr::GET(url = uri)
}
```

This is an expensive call, so I want to cache the data after the first call. So unless you explicitly state then you get a local copy of it from the packages environment after the first call.

So my aim is to include this object in the packages environment. How would I achieve this in a cran compliant way?

I've spent a lot of time [looking up environments in advanced r](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) but couldn't seem to understand how to achieve this.

Comment: [`ggmap::geocode`](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/blob/master/R/geocode.R) stores the last call as an invisible variable in the global environment, which is apparently legal, but which as a user I find less than ideal. Altering the package's environment is probably a no-go, though you could use a tempfile, storing the path as an environment variable in `options`.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I'll probably just approach the problem that way. I thought polluting the global env with invisible variables would be a no go... Given unattaching the package may not remove said variable.  It might be naive but I thought encapsulation would of been key to packages.

Comment: Check out `?ns-hooks`; you can specify to remove it with `.onUnload`, I think.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. I still think that is dangerous in general because it requires the package to successfully unload and the author to track all objects in the global env.

Comment: Oh! Here's a much better approach: https://github.com/r-lib/memoise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your `getdata` function in a `local()` call, and have it write the value to the local environment.  For example,

```
getdata <- local({
  cache <- NULL
  cachedURI <- NULL
  function(uri ="dummyuri.csv") {
    if (is.null(cache) || cachedURI != uri) {
      cache <<- httr::GET(url = uri)
      cachedURI <<- uri
    }
    cache
  }
})
```

This sets the environment of `getdata` to the one created by `local`, whose parent is the package environment.  You can modify that local one without worrying about complaints from anyone.